# Javascript check atleast 2 strings in array are non-empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of 4 strings called `options`

I'm currently checking that all elements in it are non-empty with:

```
options.every(option => Boolean(option))
```

I want instead to check that at least 2 are non-empty, some examples:

**Valid**

```
["opt1", "opt2", "", ""]  
["opt1", "opt2", "", "opt4"]
```

**Invalid**

```
["opt1", "", "", ""]  
["", "", "", ""]
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function hasEmptyStrings(arr, n) {
  return arr.filter(e => !e).length <= n
}

var arrays = [
  ["opt1", "opt2", "", ""],
  ["opt1", "opt2", "", "opt4"],
  ["opt1", "", "", ""],
  ["", "", "", ""]
]

arrays.forEach(arr => {
  console.log(hasEmptyStrings(arr, 2))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use js `filter` method to check.

```js
const arr1 = ["opt1", "opt2", "", "opt4"];
const arr2 = ["opt1", "", "", "opt4"];

const isValid = (arr) => {
  return arr.filter(item => {
    return item.length === 0;
  }) < 2;
}

console.log(isValid(arr1));
console.log(isValid(arr2));
```